# How can i fix broken link of an image being viewed in Drupalgap after being uploaded with Drupalgap also

Tags: 7, media, javascript

By using Drupalgap i create an article and attach/upload an image to that article. Image of name: `myimage.jpg` has the actual absolute path in website: `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/myimage.jpg`. In `View`(and also in `Edit`) menu tab inside Drupalgap the image seems to be broken. By debugging i get that in the View it tries to show an image with absolute path of `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/myimage.jpg` which doesn't exist. What exists in that specific folder is a renamed clone of my image with absolute path `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/1495486688801.jpg` .
To make things weirder, yesterday's articles created with the same method, which appeared also to be broken yesterday, today are shown just fine. Just fine means that the link of the image being shown points to the correct cloned image: `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/1495486688801.jpg` .
`?q=drupalgap/node/55.json` is today's article `json`  with broken links
`?q=drupalgap/node/53.json` is yesterdays's article `json` which shows image as expected.
Both get `200 OK` response.
In the 2nd json references the image `(...)"filename":"1495486688801.jpg","uri":"public://1495486688801.jpg"(...)`
 and the 1st as

```
(...)""filename":"IMG-8a92960d1864691a4e03c9cfe9ee8516-V.jpg","uri":"public://IMG-8a92960d1864691a4e03c9cfe9ee8516-V.jpg"(...).
```

Default Display in site uses `Large` image style and Drupalgap display uses `Medium` image style for the article node.
I have to mention that the same warning as the issue [776](https://github.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap/issues/776) appears to my log file.
 `WARNING: drupalgap_remove_page_from_dom() - not removing the current page (node_add_article) from the DOM!`
Maybe medium style is not created as per need of my mobile's request.

**UPDATE**

I installed the [imageinfo_cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache) module and now (confirmed after 3 newly created articles nodes with images) images are not broken in the `View` menu tab in Drupalgap. But in the `Edit` menu tab is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add this to your `settings.php` file:

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: @tyler-frankestein
I don't think that's the case. I tried your suggestion but doesn't work. Probably nothing to do with Drupalgap, but only with drupal image styles. When i debug it i see in the Edit tab that the broken image url points to a style named ll_media_default.And i don't have such a folder. Here is the exact url link: `http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/ll_media_default/public/image.jpg`